# PHP pass by reference?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

A while back, I wrote a website in php, and am now setting it up on my webserver. Back when I wrote it, everything was fine, but now, it is generating these errors:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/dragonto/public_html/source/navbar.php on line 4
class="current">Home Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/dragonto/public_html/source/navbar.php on line 4
>About Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/dragonto/public_html/source/navbar.php on line 4
>Contact Us Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/dragonto/public_html/source/navbar.php on line 4
>Projects Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/dragonto/public_html/source/navbar.php on line 4
>Tutorials
```

I'm not sure what these mean. I did research on passing by ref in PHP, and it doesn't look I made any violations. Here is the script in question:

```
<?php
    function GetScriptName()
    {
        return end(explode("/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
    }

    $Links = array(
                1 => array(1 => "Home",       2 =>     "index.php"),
                2 => array(1 => "About",      2 =>     "about.php"),
                3 => array(1 => "Contact Us", 2 =>   "contact.php"),
                4 => array(1 => "Projects",   2 =>  "projects.php"),
                5 => array(1 => "Tutorials",  2 => "tutorials.php")
            );

    echo "<nav>\n<ul>\n";

    foreach($Links as &$Link)
    {
        echo "<li";

        if($Link[2] == GetScriptName())
            echo " class=\"current\"";

        echo "><a href=\"" . $Link[2] . "\">" . $Link[1] . "</a></li>\n";
    }

    echo "</ul>\n</nav>\n";
?>
```

Comment: `return end(explode(...))` is passsing the array that explode() created to the end() function as a reference.

Comment: ok... and why doesnt that work?

Comment: It works, but in newer php versions you get the warnings because you shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: oh... ok. so ill just turn off the warning for now and fix it later

Comment: Why do you use a reference in the for loop? I think `&$Link` can just be `$Link`. Why this became a problem all of a sudden is hard to say. Maybe the server has a different PHP version (the behaviour of reference variables has been modified once in a while), or the configuration is different, causing warnings to appear more verbose.

Comment: im not sure why i used a reference there actually. probably just a habit from c++. thank you though!

Comment: @DTSCode: Pro tip: if you ever iterate by reference `&$item`, immediately `unset($item)` after the loop. Otherwise you might reassign it later on, which will result in quite a bit of hair-pulling. I've been there.

Comment: noted. ill make that change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with the call to `end`, which takes its argument by reference. But in this snippet the actual argument is not a variable, so it cannot be passed by reference. The strict standards warning complains about that.

This warning is quite benign and while you should not have production code generating warnings under any circumstances, in practice you can ignore it (the code still works as intended).

But it's also very very easy to shut it up, by introducing a variable manually:

```
$arr = explode("/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
return end($arr);
```

In this particular case it might be better to fix the issue by using something other than `end` -- something that is also more semantically accurate such as

```
return basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```